# Formatar um número com determinada quantidade de casas decimais

Tags: python

Como faço para que o usuário escolha o número de casas decimais de um número?

EX:

```
from math import pi

x = int(input('número de casas decimais de pi: '))
```

Quero poder imprimir na tela `pi` formatado com `x` casas decimais.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar a constante [`math.pi`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/math.html#math.pi) em conjunto com a função [`round`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#round), que recebe como parâmetro um número e a quantidade de casas depois da vírgula.

Ex.:

```
from math import pi

casas = int(input('Número de casas decimais de pi: '))
print(round(pi, casas))
```

<sup>Código rodando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@fernandosavio/SOPt-399427-6333)</sup>

Comment: eu gostaria de imprimir por exemplo: 'o número pi corresponde 3.14 ' # pi com x casas decimais claro, tem como usar f strings, .format ou % ?

Comment: A resposta do Anderson é a que você procura então

Comment: Você pode incluir a chamada de `round` na *f-string* também: `f'pi = {round(pi, casas)}'`

Comment: mas round() arredonda, queria tipo, o usuario diz que quer 4 casas decimais, então eu imprimo, 'pi corresponde a 3.1415'